# How to add a background color to a executable, without replacing the foreground color?

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, ls

Currently I setting the `~/.dircolors` file to:

```
LS_COLORS='fi=93:'$LS_COLORS
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS':ex=41'
```

Which are:

```
# 41  = red background
# 93  = yellow

# fi = file
# ex = file which is executable (ie. has 'x' set in permissions)
```

However the yellow color applied to non-executable files is replaced by the terminal default color `00` when the red background is applied.

On the following image:

[image]

The files `.bash_history` has not the executable flag, so its yellow color is correctly displayed. However the `.bash_profile` file has the executable flag, so the red background is applied, but the foreground color yellow was overridden by the default terminal color.

The question i show to add background to a executable, without replace its foreground color?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/466203/693277) and it states:

> These can even be combined, so that a parameter like:
>
> ```
> di=1;4;31;42
> ```
>
> in your `LS_COLORS` variable would make directories appear in bold underlined red text with a green background!

In your case you need to combine `41` and `93` when you define your `ex` entry. Your code should be:

```
LS_COLORS='fi=93:'$LS_COLORS
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS':ex=41;93'
```